# Theme folder in drupal 8

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 8, the theme folder for contributed themes seemed to have moved.

Where do themes go in drupal 8?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The theme location moved to /themes, while the core themes moved to /core/themes.

This is how the directory structure looks like in Drupal 8.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Documentation on the theme folder location and  structure was recently added to drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/2349803

Comment: It's a good practice to create a contrib folder inside your themes folder.